# Calculate time between dates of certain events within a MariaDB table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm having the following table in MariaDB 10.0.x (no window functions, "having" etc.):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test.events (
   event_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
   case_id INT UNSIGNED,
   event_ts DATE,
   added VARCHAR(50),
   removed VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (event_id)
);

INSERT INTO test.events (case_id, event_ts, added, removed)
VALUES  (1, '2020-01-02', 'A', ''),
        (2, '2020-01-03', 'B', ''),
        (2, '2020-01-03', 'A', ''),
        (1, '2020-01-04', 'B', ''),
        (2, '2020-01-05', 'D', ''),
        (1, '2020-01-06', 'D', ''),
        (1, '2020-01-07', '', 'A'),
        (1, '2020-01-08', 'C', ''),
        (2, '2020-01-08', '', 'A'),
        (1, '2020-01-09', '', 'D'),
        (1, '2020-01-10', 'A', ''),
        (1, '2020-01-11', 'F', ''),
        (2, '2020-01-12', 'F', '');
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=05bf17f735764b21d450e605526c15a3)

I want to sum only the days between the following events (including) and to group them by case_id (and for each to show the F date of the case):

- "A" added and "A" removed events or
- if ("A" removed is missing for a given case_id), then between "A" added and "F" added events

*It is guaranteed, that each case will have "A" added and "A" removed multiple times, always sequentially (added, removed, added, removed etc) but the last removed is not guaranteed, therefore we take the "F" added as the end date for the last range.

I am looking for a query that return the following result:

| case_id | days | F_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | '2020-01-11' |
| 2 | 5 | '2020-01-12' |

MariaDB 10.0.x does not support window functions and whatever I tried did not come close to the desired outcome. The table is pretty big, has hundreds of thousand of rows, so performance does matter.
The end goal is to build a report with the duration of A in each case.

Comment: How does the data shown support 5 days as the result?  All the lines are case_id=1, so the time interval is 7 days.

Comment: First of all, post a textual representation of your sample data instead of image. You're not gaining much audience if you expect people to re-write everything from your image. I mean, if it were you, wouldn't it be much easier if you can just highlight the texts, right-click "copy" and "paste" to somewhere?

Comment: Updated the example so that it is easier to grasp and test.

Comment: How did you get the `days` total for `case_id=2`? Because based on your sample data, it's only 5 days.

Comment: Also should the first occurrence between `A - added` and `A-removed` for `case_id = 1` be separated with the second occurrence (which is between `A` and `F`)?

Comment: @FanoFN, you are mistaken (for the 5 days assumption) because you are looking at the "A" removed for case_id 2.
As for the second question -> they should be aggregated, I need the total amount of days for all periods per case_id.

Comment: It's not an assumption. Your sample data clearly show 5 rows of `case_id=2`. As for your `case_id=1`, it does have 8 rows so I'm based on that. If you're doing `DATEDIFF()`, that's more than 7 days. Maybe I'm missing something here because I can't seem to figure out how it become 7.

Comment: (2, '2020-01-03', 'A', ''),
        (1, '2020-01-04', 'B', ''),
        (2, '2020-01-05', 'D', ''),
        (1, '2020-01-06', 'D', ''),
        (1, '2020-01-07', '', 'A'),
        (2, '2020-01-08', '', 'A'),
These are the rows that should be calculated for case_id=2 so they are actually 6 rows, datediff might give 5, you are correct. (see below)
You are right that the datediff for case_id=1 might show 7, which is fine. Just for the sake of simplicity in the example I am counting the rows.
Updated the example, so that it shows the datediff.

Comment: I've tried doing a query to the sample data according to your requirement. Can you please check if this is anything close to what you're trying to achieve? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b5bf68320015cc3cb9ee60583ac5a569

Comment: Hi @FanoFN, thanks for the attempt. I am actually expecting a result set, comprised of only two rows - I have posted the expected output at the last section of my question above. Your resultset does not count the 2nd period for event "A".